# Trap onClose event for instantiated form object

Tags: forms, class, ms-access, events, vba

How do you trap the *onClose* or *onUnload* events for a manually instantiated form object?

I notice that if (within my controller class), I dimension an **Access.Textbox** or **Access.CommandButton** object using the **WithEvents** keyword, then the Access VBA IDE will automatically show that object, and its available events in the comboboxes immediately above the code window.

If however, I dimension a **Form** object, or a custom Form Object using the WithEvents keyword, there is no object nor available events listed.

Form_Popup_Credentials (Form Code):

```
Public Event CustomUnLoad()

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  RaiseEvent CustomUnLoad
End Sub
```

FormController Class:

```
Dim WithEvents Loginfrm As Form_Popup_Credentials
Dim WithEvents Loginbtn As Access.CommandButton

Public Sub GetCredentials()
  ' If the Popup Credential form is not instantiated,
  ' then bring it into existence
  If Loginfrm Is Nothing Then
    Set Loginfrm = New Form_Popup_Credentials
  End If

  ' Set up a reference to the "Login" button
  Set Loginbtn = Loginfrm.SignInButton

  ' Set up the Login Button Click() event
  Loginbtn.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"

  ' Set up the Login Form's events
  Loginfrm.OnUnload = "[Event Procedure]"
  Loginfrm.OnClose = "[Event Procedure]"

  ' Show the form and give it focus
  Loginfrm.Visible = True
  Loginfrm.SetFocus
End Sub

' Fires Correctly
Private Sub Loginbtn_Click()
  MsgBox "Login Button was Clicked"

  ' If I uncomment this, then the CustomUnLoad() event fires
  ' DoCmd.Close acForm, Loginfrm.Name, acSavePrompt

  Set Loginbtn = Nothing
  Set Loginfrm = Nothing
End Sub

' Doesn't Fire
Private Sub Loginfrm_onClose()
  MsgBox "Login Form onClose() fired"
  Set Loginfrm = Nothing
  Set Loginbtn = Nothing
End Sub

' Doesn't Fire
Private Sub Loginfrm_Close()
  MsgBox "Login Form Close() fired"
  Set Loginfrm = Nothing
  Set Loginbtn = Nothing
End Sub

' Doesn't Fire
Private Sub Loginfrm_onUnload()
  MsgBox "Login Form onUnload() fired"
  Set Loginfrm = Nothing
  Set Loginbtn = Nothing
End Sub

' Doesn't Fire
Private Sub Loginfrm_Unload()
  MsgBox "Login Form Unload() fired"
  Set Loginfrm = Nothing
  Set Loginbtn = Nothing
End Sub

' This fires if the user clicks the X button to close the form,
' but not if the controller unloads the Loginfrm object
Private Sub Loginfrm_CustomUnLoad()
  MsgBox "Login Form CustomUnLoad() fired"
  Set Loginfrm = Nothing
  Set Loginbtn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried, `Dim WithEvents Loginfrm As Form` worked for me, I see the control and list of events. But `Dim WithEvents Loginfrm As Form_Popup_Credentials` even doesn't compile. If you need your custom events in the form instance, I would recommend to look at interface class and use it in the form like `Implements IMyFormEvents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your class level form variable as `Form` (or more explicit `Access.Form`) to get the standard events of Access forms:

```
Dim WithEvents Loginfrm As Access.Form
```

BTW, depending on the Access version it can be vital to make sure to set the references in your controller class to `Nothing` on `Class_Terminate`.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong.   I was trying to match the object with the declaration:

    Dim WithEvents Loginfrm As Access.Form

    Set Loginfrm = New Access.Form

But JUST changing the declaration does work.   Thanks